# How to update spring retry attributes even after context initialised

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-retry

I am using spring-retry with configurations loaded from https://launchdarkly.com/. We have this feature flag service where I can change configurations like `maxAttempts` and `interval` from the feature flag. However, spring-retry doesn't react to it. Is there any way to detect these new configurations?

Following is the example:

This is retry method:

```
@Retryable(
            exceptionExpression = "#{@config.isInExceptionListForReExecution(#root)}",
            maxAttemptsExpression = "#{@config.getMaxAttemptsForReExecution()}",
            backoff = @Backoff(delayExpression = "#{@config.getIntervalBetweenReExecution()}"))
    @Transactional(value = "transactionManagerDC")
    public CustomRule executeWithRetry(CustomRule customRule, SyncObject oldObject, SyncObject newObject, CustomRuleType type, Map<String, Object> kafkaEvent, Boolean strictValidation) {
        int retry = RetrySynchronizationManager.getContext().getRetryCount();
        logger.info("Start executing process [{}] for object [{}] with Retry [{}]", customRule.getId(), objectId, retry);
        
    }
```

And this is `config` bean, which injects feature flag service and reads the value from flags.

```
@Service
class Config {
    @Inject
    private FeatureFlagService featureFlagService;


    public boolean isInExceptionListForReExecution(Object exception1) {
        String stringFlag = featureFlagService.getStringFlag("exceptionlist");
        if (!stringFlag.contains(exception1.toString())) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int getMaxAttemptsForReExecution() {
        int maxAttempts = featureFlagService.getIntFlag("maxAttempts");
        return maxAttempts;
    }

    public int getIntervalBetweenReExecution() {
        int interval = featureFlagService.getIntFlag("interval");
        return interval;
    }

}
```

As you can see `config` bean will retrieve all configs from flags. Now, the first time what configs retrieve will be staying. If I change config it will be not considered for attempts and inteval. How to detect this change? or application needs to be restarted for that.

Comment: You'd most likely have to use the lower-level [RetryTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-retry/docs/api/current/org/springframework/retry/support/RetryTemplate.html) in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration expressions are only evaluated once, during context initialization.

There is an open new feature request to evaluate them at runtime.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/issues/184